# Why we use cloneable interface in java while making clones of the object?

Tags: java, class, cloning

I'm new to java and was studying object cloning. My question is that since *Object* class is the top most class in java and all other classes inherits this class and clone() method is defined in the *Object* class, then what is purpose of using cloneable interface? **Why can't we just override the clone() method of *Object* class in our class and return super.clone() from it**(or modify it for deep copy according to our needs)**?**

Also which is the recommended way (java standard way) of creating clones of the object? Using clone() method or creating copy constructor just like C++ which is mentioned in Andreas dolk's answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5066427/how-to-clone-object-in-java)?

Comment: you can, but just because your class extends Object, doesn't automatically means you provide an implementation yourself. There are flows that expect an instance of Cloneable, so, if you work towards that, you may want to make sure you're implementing it

Comment: [Avoid using `clone()`](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=71) - I'm pretty sure "Effective Java" also has a chapter on that. That said, use what best fits your project's style.

Comment: Yes, I found copy constructor a lot more easier than clone method from through cloneable interface. Thanks for advice @daniu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `clone` situation is **unique** and is rather anti-java-like - there's a reason its not recommended to use it in the first place. The way `Cloneable` is used in the JDK is not something you should be taking notes on - this isn't how to design APIs, nothing else in the java ecosystem works this way.

Weirdly, this is a common thing: The core parts of java often aren't java-like. For example, nobody in their right mind would make an API that defines an application by 'it has a method with the signature `public static void main(String[] args)`. The obvious design principle would be to make an abstract class or interface with an abstract `start()` method, and to make a java app you write a class that has a no-args constructor and implements/extends that interface/class. Same story for arrays: They are weird - their toString, equals, and hashCode implementations are surprising, to say the least. They aren't entirely type-safe either.

The reasons for all of this are historic: To explain them, you need to know about all sorts of things that were relevant at the time, but aren't important anymore and haven't been for decades.

Cloneable is no different. Let me explain why it works that way:

The 'system' of cloning is offered by the JDK itself, it's a built-in thing that an ordinary library could not easily make. Kinda how "`java SomeClass` invokes its main method" is part of java itself.

The system, however, needs an opt-in mechanism: The act of cloning may not make sense (what does it mean to 'clone' an `InputStream` representing a TCP network connection's incoming bytes? What does it mean to 'clone' the value of an enum which tries to guarantee that only one instance ever exists? What does it mean to 'clone' a singleton?)

Thus, 'just make all objects cloneable' is **dangerous**, so java didn't want to do that: They want you to **opt in** to it. Java wants the author of a class to explicitly say: Yup. I am clonable, using the standard mechanism (which deep-copies all fields, if memory serves).

**That is what `Cloneable` is for!** - that's *how* you say: Yup. I'm good with it. By implementing that. It's a flag.

Java could also have decided to do something like:

```
/** @cloneable */
public class Something {}
```

instead, but they didn't. If it had been designed in this more modern age, perhaps it would have looked like:

```
@Cloneable
public class Something {}
```

But annotations were introduced in java 1.5 as a demo feature in 1.6 properly. The cloneable interface is as old as java 1.0 - over a decade earlier. "add an interface that defines nothing" was the standard way to flag class properties back then, even if it isn't now.

NB: You don't *just* `implements Cloneable`, you also make a public clone method. The `implements Cloneable` part tells the cloning system: You may clone this class, for example even if it is part of the deep structure of an encompassing object that is being cloned. Making a clone method that invokes the protected JVM-provided `clone()` method that `j.l.Object` has is how you expose the API. Maybe you want to name it `copy` instead, or maybe you want cloning but not as part of your `public` API. Your question isn't about how to use clone, but why it works like it is - my advice if you want to use it is simple. Don't, write clone code yourself, or better yet, design your API with more immutables so that cloning is no longer neccessary.

Comment: I would have gone with the copy constructor way since it serves the same purpose and is more clear than cloning. Also you explained few things on Java that are not there on other platforms and only comes from experience. Thank you for writing this answer. Noted well :)

Comment: The copy constructor cannot, however, use `.clone()`, as any constructor neccessarily 'returns' a freshly created reference, it can't return a reference it obtained from something else, like a `clone()` method. Fortunately, if you clone without using `clone()`, copy constructors are a fine idea that I recommend and which e.g. `java.util.ArrayList` and co. also use (and they also do not use `clone()` in their clone impls).

Comment: Thank you for mentioning this.

Answer (score 0):

clone() method has no implementation in Object and does nothing. To make it work, your class has to implement Cloneable. This is a marker interface and adds some methods to any class inheriting it so that you can clone an object of that class.

Comment: Okay, So if neither Object class nor Cloneable interface has implementation of clone() method then how does `return super.clone() works`?